# projection wont work in mongodb c# driver

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver, projection

I have class that executes mongo queries
its works but when I send projection in query, projection won't work
and mongo return hole document

whats the matter?

```
 query = new QueryDocument( BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(queryStr));
```

`queryStr="{family:'james'},{}" =>` its ok

`queryStr="{},{family:0}" =>` not ok. return all columns, but don't want to get family column

**Remember:** just want this method. not another methods. because want send any query to mongo. I've read mapped mongo objects like ORMs.

just want this method. thanks

Comment: When you say "don't want to get family column", do you mean that you intend for the query `queryStr="{},{family:0}" =>` to return NO results?

Comment: In the second clause of your projection, could you try adding some fields to return such as `queryStr = "{},{ _id: 1, address: 1, family:0 }"` and see if family property still comes back?

Comment: One last thing I could think of is that during Deserialize process, perhaps 0 in `family:0` isn't being processed as correct type

Comment: for first comment, it returns all columns plus family. everything is ok but not in c# driver. exact query give the result I want in mongo shell. so, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into the new [C# 2.0 driver documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/)? Looks like projection is a part of the options argument you can give FindAsync

```
private static void Find(IMongoCollection<Person> mongoCollection)
    {
        var query = Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Name, "bob");

        var options = new FindOptions<Person>()
        {
            Projection = Builders<Person>.Projection
                .Include(p => p.Name)
                .Exclude(p => p.Id)
        };

        var result = await mongoCollection.FindAsync(query, options);
```

...

The BsonDocument object created from JSON {.A.}{.B.} in the question has 2 braces-pairs, and only the first one will matter (A). This is OK, since projection and query are 2 separate items.
Personally

Comment: this is not solve my question. I don't want queries and work with classes like these you mentioned. I want flexible query like I said in Bson deserialize.